# Wordpress news in their dashboard, how?

Tags: php, javascript

the question I have is how exactly does wordpress pull in their "news" content into each dashboard? I want to implement a similar concept in my script, but I don't think get_file_contents() is the best choice. What would be my best option? I was thinking using javascript, but from what I understand you cannot make requests on other domains?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking using javascript, but from what I understand you cannot make requests on other domains?

You can, via JSONP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: You can't use JSONP, when the URL is an https

Comment: @SSHThis I don't think that's true. Hell, Stripe [uses it](https://stripe.com/blog/stripejs-and-jsonp) for credit card data.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I will look into it, do you know of any good tutorials?